# restoring a mysql db via powershell

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, powershell, mysql

Say I have the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u user --password=pass dbname < backup.sql
```

It works fine in `cmd` but in PowerShell I get the following:

```
At line:1 char:53
+ "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u user --password=pass dbna ...
+                                                     ~~
Unexpected token '-u' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:56
+ "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u user --password=pass dbna ...
+                                                        ~~~~
Unexpected token 'user' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:84
+ ... rd=pass dbname < backup.sql
+                    ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

If I remove the double quotes the command gives me less errors in PowerShell but doesn't work at all in `cmd`, giving me this error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In PowerShell I get this:

```
At line:1 char:82
+ ... rd=pass dbname < backup.sql
+                    ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

So how do I feed backup.sql into `mysql`?

In Linux I think pipping would work. eg.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql -u user --password=pass dbname | cat backup.sql
```

But that gives me this error:

```
C:\Program : The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql -u user --password=pass dbname ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I re-add the double quotes it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read the file and pipe `|` it to your command. Use `&` to run the command.

`get-content 'c:\folder\backup.sql' | &"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u user --password=pass dbnamedbname`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
&cmd /c "mysql -u user --password=pass dbname < backup.sql"
```

You're essentially running in `cmd` in this case, but it's my preferred way of doing it as using `<` in PowerShell itself will not work (until it does one-day :P).

Also, I recommend putting the path to your `mysql` executable into your `PATH` environment variable so you can simply use `mysql` rather than the whole path to `mysql` just to run a command.

Comment: only this worked when I had unicode characters in my sql dump, using `get-content` and piping to mysql gave me `?` for unicode characters, although outputting `get-content` to stdout seemed ok