# Error restoring a large mysql db via powershell

Tags: powershell, mysql

I have a PowerShell script that restores a db sftp'd from another organisation on a daily basis.  Recently started receiving another database that is much bigger.  MySQL is an Azure service running v 5.6.  I did try it on a temporary v5.7 as well. 
Script works for 700MB file, but fails on > 1GB file.
Using MySQL Workbench on my desktop or on the server works, so its not a memory constraint in the server.

Code snippet is very similar to [[restoring a mysql db via powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1055797/restoring-a-mysql-db-via-powershell]):

```
$MySQLHost = 'aaaa.mysql.database.azure.com'
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'bbbb@aaaa-qa'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'zzzzz'
$MySQLDatabase = 'abcde'

$MyFilePath = "C:\SFTP\qcis_backup\"
$MyUnzipDirectory = $MyFilePath +  "database" + "\"
$MyDumpFilePath = $MyUnzipDirectory + "dump.sql"

get-content $MyDumpFilePath | &"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysql.exe" -h $MySQLHost -u $MySQLAdminUserName --password=$MySQLAdminPassword --database=$MySQLDatabase
```

Getting the following error:

Program 'mysql.exe' failed to run: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

I think it is due to the get-content being piped to the mysql cmd and trying to load in memory.
Is there any way to process this differently?  Been looking for examples for a while, but not found any I can easily use.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to add the [--quick parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_quick) to the `mysql` call. Otherwise, see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1941) how to set for mysql the memory-usage parameters.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I had tried --quick before.  also --max_allowed_packet=1073741824  .  Will try other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish I had found answer myself, but credit must go to Microsoft Support

```
$MySQLcmd = -join("&","`"C:","\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysql.exe`"")
$MySQLcmd = -join($MySQLcmd," -h ", $MySQLHost, " -u ",$MySQLAdminUserName," --password=",$MySQLAdminPassword," --database=",$MySQLDatabase," -e `"source ",$MyDumpFilePath,"`"")

invoke-expression $MySQLcmd
```